# Removing Hash from react router when using with Laravel

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-routing

Is there a way to remove # from react router when we use it Laravel. Currently I have an Laravel app where I am using one of the blade view as SPA and it has assigned to Route::('/'). I am not able to figure out to remove hash from react-router side. History or HTML5push state settings aren't working.

Is there something I have to configure from my NGINX  side ?

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Laravel's routing to route all relevant requests to your React blade view.

So, at the end of your routes.php file, you should add something like:

```
Route::any('{path?}', function () {
    return view('react');
})->where('path', '.+');
```

Or, if you want to use a controller and be able to cache your routes.:

```
Route::any('{path?}', 'ReactController@index')->where('path', '.+');
```

That takes care of the server-side stuff, I assume by your post you've already got the front-end stuff handled!

---

Just in case, for the 1.0.0-rc1 version of the React Router, you would have something like this near the top of your javascript code:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

let history = createBrowserHistory();
```

And you would later render your Router like so:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={Body}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="about" component={About}>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

---

For version 0.13.x, which you seem to be using, you should add the Router.HistoryLocation parameter on your Router.run function. For example:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

The relevant docs are on https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/doc/04%20Locations/HistoryLocation.md, unfortunately they don't seem to provide examples.

Comment: React router version we use is 0.1.3. I tried with that still no luck. Infact it adds "#/" after the route url. Like blah.com/login#/

Comment: @Meet I assume you mean you are using 0.13.x instead of 0.1.3, which is pretty ancient? I think you are now ok on the server-side, and you need to switch from Hash Location to History Location on the client side. I've added one last paragraph that should do the trick for versions 0.13.x.

Answer (score 0):

**try this** `import BrowserRouter from "react-router-dom/BrowserRouter";`

```
<BrowserRouter>
```